# Edited partial file doesn't update

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-newer

I'm using **gulp-newer** on my project to check which html file have been updating, and to prevent the reload of every html file in the project.

Everything is working fine except the **partial files**.

If I edit something in a partial the file will be update correctly but the file in which I call the partial won't be update.

I saw that there is an **options.extr**a with gulp-newer but can't make this work.

My idea is to reload every html files if I update something in one of the partials, and keep the single file reload if I work on a basic file.

**Here my task:**

```
// COMPILE SLIM TO HTML
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('slim', function () {
  return gulp.src(slim_dev + '/**/*.slim')
    // prevent server from crashing
    .pipe(plugins.plumber({ errorHandler: function(err) {
      plugins.notify.onError({
          title: "Gulp error in " + err.plugin
      })(err);
    }}))
    // compile slim to html
    .pipe(plugins.slim({
      pretty: false,
      include: true
    }))

    .pipe(plugins.newer('build/views/'))
    // minify html
    .pipe(plugins.minifyHtml())
    // copy result to build folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest(slim_build))
    // reload server on slim save
    .pipe(stream({once:true}))
    // notify when task completed
    .pipe(plugins.notify('Slim compilation completed !'));
});
```

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-partials-imported it is supposed to add the files that import the changed partial into the stream.

Comment: Do you if this plugin work only with sass file ? I need something similar for slim (html template)

Comment: Oh sorry, I saw "partials" and just went to sass. No, I doubt it works with slim files.

Comment: Poor documentation but I would say it is .newer({extra : slim_dev + '/**/*.slim', dest: 'build/views/'}) if you want to use that option.

Comment: I tried a lot of things but nothings seems to work, when I try to use the extra option, the global newer pipe stop working :/